# Can't connect to Docker container

Tags: mysql, node.js, networking, docker, restify

I have a Node.js service built with Restify and I'm trying to use Docker to wrap it all up. My Dockerfile seems to work fine and my DB and Service boots and using `docker exec` I can `curl` REST endpoints just fine. However, the ports don't seem to get exposed. I'm on a Mac if that matters. Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
MAINTAINER Oscar Godson

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs-legacy
RUN apt-get install -y npm
RUN apt-get install -y mysql-server
RUN apt-get install -y mysql-client

COPY . /src
WORKDIR /src

RUN cd /src;npm install

EXPOSE 4000

CMD ./bin/installer.sh
```

Here's installer.sh:

```
service mysql start
mysql -u root < ./bin/demo-data.sql
node index.js
```

*Note: The MySQL DB is purely for testing and local dev. We use AWS RDS for production so thats why its using root access.*

Now if I do:

```
docker run -p 4000:4000 86d57dae4522
```

And then:

```
curl http://localhost:4000/blah/ECC4E1D9-0E3C-4CE4-9D5B-2F2649A8F2FD
```

I get:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 4000: Connection refused
```

If I do it within the container with exec like:

```
docker exec -i 86d57dae4522 curl http://localhost:4000/blah/ECC4E1D9-0E3C-4CE4-9D5B-2F2649A8F2FD
```

I get (this is expected since I havent logged into my service):

```
{"message":"You don't have permissions to do that"}
```

Within my Restify server I did `0.0.0.0` for the host too since I saw some comments about Rails apps needing to set that so I thought I'd try it in Node/Restify but no luck.:

```
server.listen(process.env.PORT || 4000, "0.0.0.0", function() {
  console.log('%s listening at %s', server.name, server.url);
});
```

I've also tried  a friend suggestion of:

```
docker run --net="host" 7500cdb
```

And i read that `--hostname` puts the IP you pass it into the `/etc/hosts` so I tried (this is my computers IP)

```
docker run --hostname="192.168.2.6" 7500cdb
```

No luck with any of these. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it matters very much that you're on a Mac.

Docker doesn't run natively on the Mac, so you're running boot2docker which is setting up a little VirtualBox-based VM. It is that VM that's running Docker. When you forward some host ports, you are forwarding ports *on the VM* to the container. When you mount a local path on a container, it's a local path *on the VM*.

In your example, rather than

```
 http://localhost:4000/blah/ECC4E1D9-0E3C-4CE4-9D5B-2F2649A8F2FD
```

you need to run

```
  http://$(boot2docker ip):4000/blah/ECC4E1D9-0E3C-4CE4-9D5B-2F2649A8F2FD
```

You can also run `boot2docker ip` and save that address in your `/etc/hosts` file under a friendly name, if you like. (This can be helpful if your container is going to serve SSL certs).

Comment: Note that nowadays `boot2docker` is no longer used... see [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/mac/) for more.

Comment: Correct, @Claudiu. However, you still run in a VM and so all the nuttiness still applies.

Comment: Aye true! The only difference is now you would do `docker-machine ip default` instead of `boot2docker ip`